# Audio on TS File Falls Progressively Out of Sync

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I would really appreciate some help with this...

I have a .ts file I've downloaded from the internet, when I play in Quicktime the video progressively falls behind the audio. It becomes noticeable after a couple of minutes and is a few seconds out after about ten minutes. It plays fine in VLC, but I want to be able to play on my AppleTV which does the same as Quicktime.

I've tried everything I can think of to resolve...

- Convert with VLC, which does work, but every few seconds the audio skips.
- Convert with Handbrake, which again works, but every few seconds the audio skips like with VLC.
- Convert with FFMpeg using -async, but I get the same result again with the audio skips.
- Extracted the audio and video to two separate files and recreated a new file with FFMpeg, this makes no difference and is the same as playing the original file.
- Tried "stretching" the audio with FFMpeg using "aresample=async=1000", which synchronises but the audio is distorted.

I think the audio skips I'm getting from the -async option are caused because the audio is being trimmed to sync with the video. What I want to do is adjust the video to fit with the audio and leave the audio unchanged.

I've tried to do this with -vsync, but the the results are the same as the original file. The FFMpeg user guide says the following:

***With -map you can select from which stream the timestamps should be taken. You can leave either video or audio unchanged and sync the remaining stream(s) to the unchanged one.***

But I cannot figure out the syntax. This is what I'm trying but the output is the same as the original...

***ffmpeg -vsync 1 -I test.ts -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -y test.mp4***

I've tried the above using vsync with 0, 1 and 2, but the result is still the same.

Could anyone please help me with the syntax to sync the video stream to the audio stream and leave the audio unchanged? Or suggest an alternative method I could use?

Any help would be really, really appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the ffprobe for test.ts...

```
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'TEst.ts':
  Duration: 02:13:05.51, start: 1.406000, bitrate: 4579 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 1411200000.00 tbc
  Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s
```

Comment: Have you check the load of the computer when play this video? Do you see similar effect when play other videos?

Comment: Hi Romeo, it's a fairly new MacBook Pro and the load is fine. It happens with other files I've downloaded from the same website, but no other files.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the 'atempo' filter. The best way to explain it is for me to relate my project.

I'm recasting 23.976fps video to 24fps. I'm not changing the frames, just forcing the framerate from 24/1.001fps to 24fps, thereby speeding up the video by a factor of 1.001. In the same transcode, I speed up audio by a factor of 1.001 via 'atempo=1.001'. The result runs slightly faster -- running time actually becomes the same as seen in a theater -- and video and audio are perfectly synced, even for a 2 hour movie,

In my case,

```
ffmpeg -i SOURCEVIDEO -filter_complex "[0:v]settb=expr=1/24,setpts=expr=N[v];[0:a]atempo=1.001[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -codec:v h264 -codec:a aac -r 24 TARGETVIDEO
```

In your case you don't need to transcode the video, just the audio, so

```
ffmpeg -i test.ts -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=?????[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -codec:v copy -codec:a aac TARGET
```

I'm going to assume you know what all that means. If you don't, or if you have any questions, ask and I'll help further.

In your case, you need to determine what `?????` is. If your audio is running too slow, pick `?????` that is greater than 1.0. If your audio is running too fast, pick `?????` that is less than 1.0.

Go to the end of the video and catch the last audio that is noticeably off. To the best of your ability, determine how much the audio timing is off (in seconds), plus the total running time at that point. The value of `?????` will be an advance or retard factor,

(total+/-off)/total

needed to bring them into sync.